# list comprehesion in pandas

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've got problem with list comprehesion. I've wrote code as follows to get list with nan's where value in second column of my df is True

```
[np.nan for name in data_col.iloc[:,0] if data_col.iloc[:,1]==True]
```

Instead of expected output I've received error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can anybody help with it?

Comment: Your `data_col.iloc[:, 1] == True` is ambiguous: `data_col.iloc[:,1]==True` may return `[True, False, True, ...]` which is hard to make a _truth value_, just as its error is stating.

Comment: Pandas needs you to specify how yo turn `data_col.iloc[:,1]` into `True` or `False` with one of the methods mentioned in the error.

Comment: Ok, but in second column I've already have only T/F values. So what is wrong with this columns. I've tested solution with change values in second column on 0/1 and conditon on ==1 but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if statement you are returning an entire list every time you loop and execute your if statement you need to access a single element

```py
for x in range(len(data_col.iloc[:,0])):
    if data_col.iloc[x,1]:
        np.nan
```

or this should work I just don't normally write one liners.

```py
[np.nan for x in range(len((data_col.iloc[:,0])) if data_col.iloc[x,1]]
```